# Javascript [remove: function] logging custom array CQ Ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

While logging a list of child nodes that I obtained from `CQ.Ext.tree.TreeNode.childnodes`,  I am  getting the [log as remove:function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIgHH.png) for that array. Because of that, I wasn't able to iterate it.

Kindly help me on this please.

Sample code:

```
console.log(node.childNodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are iterating over it using **for...in** looping:

```
for (node in node.childNodes)
    // do smth there with node
```

You should not use this kind of loop, because it iterates over both array indices and property keys.

Instead, use either simple **for** loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
    // do smth with node 'node.childNodes[i]'
}
```

either **for each...in**:

```
node.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    // do smth with node
});
```